# Injecting bean 1 into bean 2: will changes in states of bean 1 be reflected in bean 2?

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2

GlassFish4, JSF2.2, JavaEE7:

ManagedBean `controllerBean` is injected in ManagedBean `pb` (for progressBar):

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Pb implements Serializable{

    public Pb() {
    }

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{controllerBean}")
    ControllerBean controllerBean;

    public void setControllerBean(ControllerBean controllerBean) {
        this.controllerBean = controllerBean;
    }

    public Integer getProgress() {
        return controllerBean.getNumberOfComputations();
    }
}
```

-> the method `getProgress()` returns different values as the Integer `numberOfcomputations` in `controllerBean` increments.

BUT when I use `@Inject` instead of `@ManagedProperty`:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Pb implements Serializable{

    public Pb() {
    }

    @Inject
    @ControllerBean controllerBean;


    public Integer getProgress() {
        return controllerBean.getNumberOfComputations();
    }
}
```

Then `getProgress()` keeps returning 0, which is the initial state of `numberOfComputations` in controllerBean, even if this Integer increases rapidly in `controllerBean`.

What is going on?

Comment: You can't mix annotation from JSF beans and CDI beans. Why do it anyway? Also I don't see any @Inject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace all JSF annotation by CDI's ones:

```
@ManagedBean => @Named

@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped => @javax.faces.view.ViewScoped

@ManagedProperty => @Inject
```